# Prefix.pch with Modules Enabled?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, compiler-optimization, precompiled-headers, llvm-clang

If I have "Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)" set to "Yes" in Build Settings, shouldn't I get rid of the `Prefix.pch` precompiled header file? If not, what are the reasons I should keep it?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to keep it for frameworks you use that don't have corresponding modules, such as the [Facebook SDK for iOS](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/).

Comment: OK. But, if I know I won't be using those, can I delete it?